# Filtering Data based on another dataframe based on two rows

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have two Datasets.

The first dataset includes Companies, the Quarter and the corresponding value from the whole timespan.

```
    Quarter      Date            Company   value
    2012.1       2012-12-28      x         1
    2013.1       2013-01-02      y         2
    2013.1       2013-01-03      z         3
```

Companies again are in the dataset over the whole time and show up multiple times.

The other dataset is an index which includes a company identifier and the quarter in which it existed in the index (Companies can be in the index in multiple quarters).

```
    Quarter      Date            Company   value
    2012.1       2012-12-28      x         1
    2014.1       2013-01-02      y         2
    2013.1       2013-01-03      x         3
```

Now I need to only select the companies which are in the index at the same time (quarter) as I have data from the first dataset.

In the example above I would need the data from company x in both quarters, but company y needs to get kicked out because the data is available in the wrong quarter.

I tried multiple functions including filter, subset and match but never got the desired result. It always filters either too much or too little.

```r
data %>% filter(Company == index$Company & Quarter == index$Quarter)
```

or

```r
data[Company == index$Company & Quarter = index$Quarter,]
```

Something with my conditions doesn't seem right. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not `merge` the two data frames on *Company* and *Quarter*?

Comment: Try with join or `merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `dplyr`'s powerful `join` functions. Here `inner_join` might help you

```
dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2, by=c("Company", "Quarter"))
```